# Get name of current table by resultSet on RowMapper

Tags: java, database-table, database-metadata

It's possible get name of current table, on implementation of RowMapper.
I try by metadata, but not have sucess

Comment: what implementation do you mean?

Comment: I am using the SpringData JdbcTemplate to run queries on the database, and implements the RowMapper to map the resultset

Comment: What DB driver jar are you using?

Comment: H2 database org.h2.Drive

Comment: Read http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html for getTableName() and check if any of the metioned conditions for getTableName() == null applies to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to determine the tablename by

```
 ResultSet.getMetaData().getTableName(int column)
```

As both ResultSet and ResultSetMetaData are only interfaces, the implementation depends on the database driver your are using.

So, if this method does not deliver the tablename:

- the driver implementation does not support it.
- the column does not have a table associated with (e.g. select sysdate ...)

For example current oracle db driver does not support it.

For H2, check http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html , it describes the behaviour of getTableName() depending on the selected Compatibility Mode.